# Find a string in Html and get value after

Tags: java, html, regex, groovy, soapui

I'm posting to a webpage and in my response I get a big chunk of HTML that will change next request. 
With groovy I'd like to find this string:

```
var WPQ1FormCtx = {"ListData":{"owshiddenversion":23,
```

The value "23" will change next time I post to the webpage, and I need that value.

With `.contains` I'll find if string exists.

```
def htmlParse = Jsoup.parse(htmlResponse)
log.info a.contains('var WPQ1FormCtx = {"ListData":{"owshiddenversion":23,')
```

But I need to write out the value after `owshiddenversion` in the string `'var WPQ1FormCtx = {"ListData":{"owshiddenversion":xxxxx,` 
that can be anything from 1 to 100 000.

Comment: `\d{1,6}` shoud match more than one digit and up to 6. This mean it can also match numbers greater than `100000`, as long as they are no more than 6 digits long.

Comment: Hi, could you please show in my example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the string you are matching correctly, this will help you to do it in pure Groovy. You could wrap it in a method that is called as the test instead of .contains()

```
def stringPortion = 'var WPQ1FormCtx = {"ListData":{"owshiddenversion":23,'

def match = stringPortion =~ /"owshiddenversion":(\d{1,6})/  //capture the match with ()

def matchPortion = match[0][1] //first capture in match

if (matchPortion) {
    println matchPortion
    def number = matchPortion.toInteger()
    if (number > 100000) {
        println 'number > 100000'
    }
    else if (number <= 10000) {
        println 'number <= 10000'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

(I hope I will not attract too many downvotes...)

I've never used Java, but playing around [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_java_online.php) I could come up with an example which uses a regex:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
public class HelloWorld{
     public static void main(String []args){
        String str = new String("before the number 234123");
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("before the number (\\d{1,6})");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
        matcher.matches();
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
     }
}
```

If you really have that number to be less then or equal to 100000, then you have to write a slightly more complex regex which should say "either 100000 or a 5 digit number".

Answer (score 0):

the following code block can work

```
def json = WPQ1FormCtx 
def parsedJson = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(json)
def owshiddenversion= parsedJson.findIndexOf { it.key == 'owshiddenversion' }
```